# Show C is not 1-error correcting by using Slepian decoding

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, coding-theory

Let C $\subseteq$ $ \mathbb{Z}_2^5$be a linear code with generator matrix $$G=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1\\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1\\0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$.

Show that C is not 1-error correcting by finding a received word that cannot be correctly decoded using Slepian decoding.

Could anyone point me some direction to solve this question?

Comment: I have heard of Slepian - cited his paper in my own even. I think I know what decoding is. But I have not heard of "Slepian decoding". Care to enlighten me? However, it may not be necessary to know the details here, because the sum of the first two rows is of weight two, so there's gotta be a weight one error pattern that cannot be correctly decoded.